# Inverter uma string corretamente

Tags: c, string

Não consigo imprimir o vetor ao contrário, nesse caso, a palavra digitada tem que ter exatamente 6 letras. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char nome[7],letra;
  int i,aux=0;

  printf("Digite uma palavra:");
  scanf("%s",nome);

  for(i=5;i>=0;i--){
    letra=nome[aux];//letra recebe o primeiro caractere do vetor
    nome[aux]=nome[i];//a primeira posiçao do vetor recebe o caractere da ultima
    nome[i]=letra;//a ultima posiçao recebe o caractere da primeira posiçao que foi armazenada na variavel letra
    aux++;//repetir o processo usando a segunda letra

  }
  printf("\n%s",nome);












    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acho que nem precisaria manipular a *string*, já que pede apenas para imprimir invertido e não inverter a original, mas mantive a mudança no objeto porque pode ser que o enunciado pode estar errado, se for isso mesmo deveria fazer um código mais simples ainda.

Essa variável auxiliar só serve para causar confusão e o maior problema é que está invertendo dos dois lados, então tudo o que está fazendo de um lado está desfazendo do outro, tem que fazer a operação até a metade, o que inclusive deixa mais eficiente.

Observe que melhorei várias outras coisas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nome[7];
    printf("Digite uma palavra:");
    scanf("%6s", nome);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char letra = nome[i];
        nome[i] = nome[5 - i];
        nome[5 - i] = letra;
    }
    printf("\n%s", nome);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LedfjG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InvertStringc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/InvertString.c).

Comment: A questão era pra inverter a posição dos caracteres mesmo e printar o vetor normalmente.Entendi o seu código,Obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo clássico desse algoritmo pode ser encontrado no famoso livro [The C Programming Language](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hilder/cs833/Other%20Reference%20Materials/The%20C%20Programming%20Language.pdf) (capítulo 3, página 55-56):

```
#include <string.h>

void inverter(char * s) {
    int c, i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--)
        c = s[i], s[i] = s[j], s[j] = c;
}
```

Integrando a função ao seu código, as coisas ficariam mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void inverter(char * s) {
    int c, i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--)
        c = s[i], s[i] = s[j], s[j] = c;
}

int main() {
    char nome[7];
    printf("Digite uma palavra: "); 
    scanf("%6s", nome);
    inverter(nome);
    printf("%s\n", nome);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SecretDownrightBooleanlogic)

Comment: Não conhecia essa "concatenação" de atribuições usando a vírgula. Tem mais material no assunto?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Isso se chama [Comma Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). O livro citado na resposta possui uma explicação mais detalhada na pagina 169.